# Reproduce a figure without data

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to reproduce the wiskers and boxplots below, but I don't have any data. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Is it the making up data or making the plot you don't know how to do?

Comment: This may help you: [metaDigitise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metaDigitise/vignettes/metaDigitise.html).

Comment: @user 438383 I don't have any data with regards the plot

Comment: @Rstudent what did you try first? Please show some evidence that you tried to solve this first before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by feeding the `aes` with `ymin`, `lower`, `middle`, `upper`, and `ymax`, rather than a continuous `y`.

```
df <- data.frame(Var = c("Overall", "Outputs", "Impact", "Environment"),
                 Q0 = c(2.35, 2.50, 1.75, 1.75), 
                 Q1 = c(2.90, 2.85, 2.80, 2.75),
                 Q2 = c(3.10, 3.00, 3.35, 3.05),
                 Q3 = c(3.40, 3.25, 3.55, 3.75),
                 Q4 = c(3.60, 3.50, 4.00, 4.00),
                 Mu = c(3.35, 3.15, 3.6, 3.65))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Var,ymin=Q0,lower=Q1,middle=Q2,upper=Q3,ymax=Q4))+
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity") +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, aes(y = Mu), geom="point", shape=20, size=5, color="red", fill="red") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could insert some made-up illustrative data in a `tribble` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~name, ~gpa,
  "box1", 3,
  "box1", 3.3,
  "box1", 3.7,
  "box2", 1.5,
  "box2", 3.4,
  "box2", 2.7) |> 
  ggplot(aes(name, gpa)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>